# What is the purpose of "msg" in this try-except block?

Tags: python, sockets, except, try-except

I was reading the Python socket programming tutorial, and I found this except block in the program:

```
except socket.error, msg:
    print 'Failed to create socket. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ' , Error message : ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit();
```

What exactly is "msg" referencing (I know it is referencing the error message); but what IS it and where does it pull it from?

Sorry if this question is worded poorly.  I'm not certain what exactly I should be asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`msg`is the actual exception object that is being caught. For example:

```
try:
    x = Exception()
    raise x
except Exception, msg:
    assert x is msg
```

The modern way of writing that statement would be

```
except socket.error as msg
```

Answer (score 1):

`msg` **is the explanation of the error** !

This exception is raised for [socket-related errors](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.error). The accompanying value is either a string telling what went wrong or a pair (errno, string) representing an error returned by a system call, similar to the value accompanying [os.error](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.error). See the module [errno](https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html#module-errno), which contains names for the error codes defined by the underlying operating system.